# Regarding string object pool in PermGC

Tags: java, string

I heard that string object pool exists in the PermGC and when a string intern is executed, it checks the pool first to see if an equivalent string object exists, if it does not exist, it creates one and returns a reference to the pooled instance.

But here is my first question.

I think that object is created on the heap, especially in the young generation first. If it survives during few garbage collections, it moves to the old generation. can anybody explain how the string object goes to the pool that exists in the Perm GC?

second question:

String s = "test";
s = "test1";

If i reassign "test1" to a reference s and continue to use "test1", does it mean that "test" (created on the young generation) will be garbage collected?

third question:
How is the string object pool related to the runtime constant pool?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What makes you think the interned String first goes to the young generation? The `String#intern()` method is a native method. It's certainly very possible for an implementation to move it right into the permgen.

Second question: if there's no other references to that `"test"` String instance, it's eligible for garbage collection. Same story if it's interned. Even an interned String that no longer has any active references can be garbage collected. This might not have been the case in older JVMs, though. And it can be implementation-specific, I guess.

As for the third question, I do not know. All I know is that String literals from source code are placed into the same pool. If you were to construct a String that's equal to a String constant from source and then intern it, you'd be returned the instance that was used to represent the constant. Think of this as String literals having been interned right away.

EDIT: just read your initial few sentences again and I think I see the reason for the confusion. When you call `intern()` on a String, and no equal String is in the pool yet, then it's not first gonna construct an equivalent String. It'll just move the instance you called `intern()` on to the pool rather than returning a new reference. [That's how it's stated in the JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29).

Comment: Are you saying that only String s = new String("test"); will create a string object on the young generation first?

Comment: @user826323 Well, that would result in an object in the young generation. Then if you call `intern()` on it, that instance `s` is either gonna be put in the permgen pool if no equivalent String was there yet, **or** you'll be returned the previously pooled instance which would leave you with two references. But if you had `String s = "test";` in code, than you will effectively have `"test"` in the pool since it's a source code literal.

Answer (score 0):

Strings go to intern pool in two cases:

- you explicitly call intern() method on the String object
- you initialize it with a literal (you give the explicit content of the String), since Java automatically interns String literals.

The pool is organized as a table, once a String is interned it is added to the pool if the value is not yet present otherwise a reference to the existing entry is used.

"test" in your case is supposed to go to the pool and not to the young space, anyway cleanup of Strings not referenced anymore is performed there too (I cannot say if it is part of the same GC process used for the heap nor if this behavior is standard)